# javascript array filter multiple and condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, arrow-functions

How to filter a javascript array with multiple matching conditions.
The below code returns all the data, instead of just 2.

Code:

```
this.entityTypes = codeList.Values.filter(c => c.CodeValue === 'CRD_CRE_INS' || 'CRD_EEA_BRA');
```

Sample JSON Array:-

```
const codeList.Values = [{
    "CodeValue": "CRD_CRE_INS",
    "CodeValueDisplay": "CRD Credit Institution",
  },
  {
    "CodeValue": "CRD_EEA_BRA",
    "CodeValueDisplay": "EEA Branch",
  },
  {
    "CodeValue": "CRD_NON_EEA_BRA",
    "CodeValueDisplay": "Non-EEA Branch",
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `'CRD_EEA_BRA'` is always true, you have to change the code to:

```
this.entityTypes = codeList.Values.filter(c => c.CodeValue === 'CRD_CRE_INS' ||  c.CodeValue === 'CRD_EEA_BRA');
```

Answer (score 4):

An `||` doesn't work that way

You could put the values in array instead. This makes it easily scale-able for number of conditions

```
this.entityTypes = codeList.Values
                   .filter(c => ['CRD_CRE_INS','CRD_EEA_BRA'].includes(c.CodeValue) );
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition of ===, you can use an array of target values and check if the element matches any of the target values

```
const values = ["CRD_CRE_INS","CRD_EEA_BRA"]
this.entityTypes = codeList.Values.filter(c => values.includes(c.CodeValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best solution but..you can use RegExp for custom filtering..

```
#Filtering function
const filterExp = (exp) => new RegExp(exp);

#Example 1
const values = data.filter((e) => filterExp('CRD').test(e.CodeValue));
console.log(values)
//Output
[ { CodeValue: 'CRD_CRE_INS',CodeValueDisplay: 'CRD Credit Institution' },
  { CodeValue: 'CRD_EEA_BRA', CodeValueDisplay: 'EEA Branch' },
  { CodeValue: 'CRD_NON_EEA_BRA',CodeValueDisplay: 'Non-EEA Branch' } ]

#Example 2
const values = data.filter((e) => filterExp('EEA').test(e.CodeValue));
console.log(values)
//Output
[ { CodeValue: 'CRD_EEA_BRA', CodeValueDisplay: 'EEA Branch' },
  { CodeValue: 'CRD_NON_EEA_BRA', CodeValueDisplay: 'Non-EEA Branch' } ]
```